# Do I create a new view in React for each of my tables in my backend?

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm new to react and I'm struggling to understand its proper structure. I have three tables in my back end which is written in Express.js, but that's beside the point. the point is I want to implement a CRUD ui interface for my tables in React. Do I respect the single web page application and have them all in the same page or do I create a different view for each table?

Comment: Do you want to render all 3 tables in the same page? Or just single one?

Comment: I want two pages total, first page for table #1 and #2 and second page for table #3

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the backend has nothing to do with how you should design your frontend.

Backend should be structured in a way so your server (Basically a computer) can work with it in the most efficient way and your Frontend should be designed that your end user (Basically a human) can work with it in the most efficient way possible.

You can manage so many tables in one single view and yet you can manage one table in so many views.

You design your database based on the data structure you have and the type of queries you're going to run.

And for the frontend, design the pages based on how your user will enjoy. anything in between can be done by some codes. You can split data with some codes to use them in more than one table or you can add data from many views piece by piece.

Comment: Interesting thank you! So I have decided to render each table in a view for now, but does that mean I have to create a new .js file for each view's component?

Comment: You can have more than one component in one file but i prefer having different components in different files on most cases which is kinda a long topic to be discussed here. I recommend looking into some sample react projects and read some related articles.

Comment: Thank you! And what do you think it's fine if I name my components the same as my tables name?

Comment: I don't know how you named your tables but there is some best practice naming for both database and react apps. It is okay in general but still you can read some articles about this too.

Comment: Always think of back and front end projects as a completely independent project. What you do on the backend has nothing to do with your views. You can be as creative as you want on the front layer, e.g: you may wish to have modal for adding new data into your database or just a page.  
If your backend exposes apis for your CRUD application, then make request from your front-end for each of these actions, the views or naming here doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

As defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)

> SAP is a web application or web site that interacts with the user by
>   dynamically rewriting the current page rather than loading entire new
>   pages from a server

Although you may split your views into multiple pages as you wish in react, this doesn't mean you violate the single page because if you check well, your entire app is rendered into one file called app.js/index.js depending on your setup.

You mainly accomplish this views split with `router`, and the reason why many router libraries provide `Link` component is to prevent the default behavior of `<a href="your_link_here">Link</a>`, by default this makes a server request to load page while SAP is meant to be decoupled entirely from the backend and load resources dynamically and added to the page as necessary with Javascript, usually in response to user actions.

This way you backend needs just to expose Apis that your react app will consume.

Comment: Thank you! Will a component for each crud operation be okay?

Comment: I think you only need like two components. one form component (create + update, this can do both) and another for showing data in a table (read) with a button on each row for deleting.

Comment: You might need another one for warning before deleting or just use a simple Javascript alert. I am assuming your project is for learning purpose.